# 2-way sync between ms exchange calendar and Java app

Tags: java, calendar, exchange-server

we are developing a CRM app which holds customer meeting info. Users have requested that their Outlook calendars should reflect the activity they have booked in the CRM application and vice versa.

Is there any solution to achieve this? Preferably not using any plugins or installs on the end user's PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll throw my two cents here.

I implemented a two-way calendar synchronization solution at where I work, against a Ruby-on-Rails app. The requirement was almost identical to what you listed, although the synchronization has to be near real-time. What I did was to write a Windows service using Exchange Web Services (not the current managed API). Both Push and Pull notifications were used -- push notification to provide real-time sync while pull sync to sync out-of-date local copies. It was a little bit challenging back then, as the documentation was very poor, and the API was very verbose. The new managed API is much more terse.

The service has been running well for more than almost two years now.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the EWS Java API from Microsoft.  It makes doing this type of thing a snap.  No need to re-invent the wheel writing your own interface.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this blog post](http://www.psyked.co.uk/file_formats/icalendar/creating-outlook-calendar-events-through-http-links.htm) and [the iCal](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445) spec, you ought to be able to do this by sending the user a link to an iCal event.